# Working out travel time from gdistance's conductance values in R?

Tags: r, cost-surface, tobler

**Introduction**

This question is indirectly related to a previous post of mine ([Calculating accumulated walking pace from starting location outwards using R?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/280105/r-how-to-calculate-accumulated-walking-pace-from-a-starting-location-outwards)), but asks guidance about a different aspect, that's why I am creating a new post.

I have put togheter some doce (below) to provide a reproducible example.

**Aim**

Calculating cumulative cost-surface expressing walking time from a given location outwards.

**Background**

I have followed the code provided by this source (https://mran.microsoft.com/snapshot/2014-11-17/web/packages/gdistance/vignettes/gdistance.pdf) to calculate an accumulated cost surface from a location outwards, using the 'gdistance' package. The cost surface has to represent walking time according to the Tobler's hiking function (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tobler%27s_hiking_function).

```
## EXAMPLE ##

library(gdistance)

# create the data to work with
dtm <- raster(system.file("external/maungawhau.grd", package="gdistance"))
A <- c(2667670,6479000)

# define the Tobler's function, re-expressed not in Kmh but in meters per hour
tobler.mperh <- function(x){ (6 * exp(-3.5 * abs(x + 0.05))) * 1000 }

altDiff <- function(x){x[2] - x[1]}
hd <- transition(dtm, altDiff, 8, symm=FALSE)
slope <- geoCorrection(hd,scl=FALSE)

adj <- adjacent(x=dtm, cells=1:ncell(dtm), direction=8)
speed <- slope
speed[adj] <- tobler.mperh(slope[adj]) #this should be speed in m/h

#sanity check for speed:
plot(raster(speed)) #flat areas should feature around 5000 m/h

#geocorrection divides speed by distance (i.e., cells' centers)
conduct <- geoCorrection(speed, scl=FALSE) # conductance = speed/distance = 1/travel time
plot(raster(conduct))

cost_surface <- accCost(conduct, A)
plot(cost_surface)      # = 1/travel time
```

**Workflow followed**

The abovementioned PDF was implementing Tobler's function not to create an accumulated cost surface but to calculate shortest path. With reference to the code above, I am rather confused about how to work out travel time from the last result of the code, i.e. the accumulated cost surface.

In other words:

all seems fine till the calculation of the speed (meters per hour) data (see code flagged by *#sanity check for speed*). The speed raster I got (see below) seems to make sense, since flat areas feature a speed of about 5000 m/h (i.e., 5 Kmh) as predicted by the Tobler's function.

[image]

The above is confirmed by the following chart of speed vs slope:
[image]

The subsequent operation that uses `geocorrection` divide the speed (m/h) by the distance (i.e., distance between cell's center), so producing what is called `conductance`. The latter (according to the abovementioned PDF) is equal to `1/travel time`.

The *accumulated conductance* looks like the image below (see *plot(cost_surface)      # = 1/travel time*):

[image]

**Issue**

In an attempt to devise the travel time (tv), I simple calculated the reciprocal of the accumulated cost, the latter being based on the conductance data. But taking the inverse produces a raster that seems to make no sense:

```
tv <-cost_surface
values(tv) <- 1/values(cost_surface)
```

[image]

**Question:**

Is the issue caused by including 0 values into the calculation of the reciprocal?

Answer (score 0):

Extracted from "R Package gdistance: Distances and Routes on Geographical Grids" (Jacob van Etten)

*What do these values mean? The function geoCorrection divides the values in the matrix between the distance between cell centres. So, with our last command we calculated this:
**conductance = speed/distance**
This looks a lot like a measure that we are more familiar with:
**traveltime = distance/speed**
In fact, the conductance values we have calculated are the reciprocal of travel time.
**1/traveltime = speed/distance = conductance***

So, just invert the last formula, so: ***traveltime = 1/conductance***

```
tv <- raster(conduct)
values(tv) <- 1/values(raster(conduct))

plot(tv)
points(as_Spatial(ps)
```

You should see something like this (conductance):
[image]

...to this (traveltime):
[image]

[Here I wrote a post about the topic with other examples and layouts](https://www.modlearth.com/2022/07/20/gdistance/). There a final test of the outputs in order to see if travel times are as expected.